# Partition on Exisiting Table with Millions of Record

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-partitioning, data-partitioning

I need you suggestion on creating a partition on a table having millions of record.

table definitions

1. CompanyId
2. Type_Of_Data
3. Emp_id
4. Destination
5. Destination_id

Now here for a single company ,type of data and emp_id can be different

```
 COMPANY_ID   TYPE_OF_DATA EMP_ID

 A  EMP_DATA          A1   
 A  EMP_DATA          A2
 A  EMP_DATA          A3
 A  EMP_DATA          A4
 A  EMP_ADDRESS_DATA  A1   
 A  EMP_ADDRESS_DATA  A2
 A  EMP_ADDRESS_DATA  A3
 A  EMP_ADDRESS_DATA  A4
 B  EMP_DATA          B1
 B  EMP_DATA          B2
 B  EMP_DATA          B3
 B  EMP_DATA          B4
 B  EMP_ADDRESS_DATA  B1   
 B  EMP_ADDRESS_DATA  B2
 B  EMP_ADDRESS_DATA  B3
 B  EMP_ADDRESS_DATA  B4
```

My basic selecting  will be on company_id and then type of data and emp_id

I was thinking of creating a List - Hash or List -List Partition.

Can anyone suggest something else and how to add partition to the existing table will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add any partition to an existing "non-partitionized" table. You have to create a new table and copy your data into it.
Have a look at [DBMS_REDEFINITION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_redefi.htm#CBBJJAIF) which helps you to do this without any downtime of your application.

A composite List-List partition would be this one:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE
(
COMPANY_ID VARCHAR2(100),
TYPE_OF_DATA VARCHAR2(100),
EMP_ID  VARCHAR2(10),
...
)
PARTITION BY LIST (COMPANY_ID)
    SUBPARTITION BY LIST (TYPE_OF_DATA) SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE 
        (
        SUBPARTITION EMP VALUES ('EMP_DATA'),
        SUBPARTITION EMP_ADDRESS VALUES ('EMP_ADDRESS_DATA'),
        SUBPARTITION MISCELLANEOUS VALUES (DEFAULT) -- if needed
        )
(
PARTITION COMPANY_A VALUES ('A'),
PARTITION COMPANY_B VALUES ('B'),
PARTITION COMPANY_C VALUES ('C'),
PARTITION COMPANY_OTHER VALUES (DEFAULT)
);
```

In case you can get additional companies in your table consider `RANGE` partition instead.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer :Can you please tell me how to add a new partition and sub partition to this table ?

Comment: Simply add a partition `ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD PARTITION COMPANY_D_TO_G VALUES ('D','E','F','G');`. Subpartitions are created automatically as defined by template.

Comment: :I means if another subpartition comes up like EMP_SPOUSE ,then I don't want it to go under default  subpartition ,then how will I add that , I am asking because I need to do this dynamic

Comment: `ALTER TABLE my_table SET SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE (SUBPARTITION EMP VALUES ('EMP_DATA'),
        SUBPARTITION EMP_ADDRESS VALUES ('EMP_ADDRESS_DATA'), SUBPARTITION SPOUSE VALUES ('EMP_SPOUSE')).`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly partition an existing non-partitioned table. You will need to create an interim table/new table depending on the following methods to partition:

- **[DBMS_REDEFINITION](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/partitioning-an-existing-table)**

  1. Create a Partitioned Interim Table
  2. Start the Redefinition Process
  3. Create Constraints and Indexes (Dependencies)
  4. Complete the Redefinition Process
- **[EXCHANGE PARTITION](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/partitioning-an-existing-table-using-exchange-partition#split_partition)**

  1. Create a Partitioned Destination Table
  2. EXCHANGE PARTITION
  3. SPLIT PARTITION (If required to split single large partition into smaller partitions)